# Find nodes based on parent relationships in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

**Problem**

I have a neo4j graph database with data that looks like the following:

[image]

`Item A` is missing in `Category 1` and `Item B` is missing in `Category 2`. `Category 2` is a child of `Category 1`.

When an item is missing in a category, it's also missing in all child categories.

**Question**

How do you query neo4 for all items missing in `Category 2` including those items missing in parent categories? Bear in mind that `Category 1` itself could also have a parent with missing items, which should also be included. A `Category` can only have one or zero parents.

**What I've tried**

I tried using the following cypher query but it doesn't work. I think this is because the variable relationship is on the `MISSING_IN` relationship, but it should really be on the `CHILD_OF` relationship.

```
MATCH (Category {name:2})<-[r:MISSING_IN*]-(Item) RETURN Item
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a root category node, this query should work :

```
MATCH 
  path=shortestPath((cat2:Category {name:'2'})-[:CHILD_OF*]->(catRoot:Category {name:'0'} )),
  (n)<-[:MISSING_IN]-(item:Item)
WHERE
  n IN nodes(path)
RETURN item
```

Answer (score 1):

The following query do the trick and will also handle the case when Category 2 does not have any parent and is also validated by the console link provided by @logisima

```
MATCH (c:Category {name:2})-[:CHILD_OF*0..]->(parent:Category)<-[:MISSING_IN]-(i:Item)
RETURN c.name, collect(i) as items
```

Answer (score 1):

try the below cypher

```
MATCH path=(c:Category{name:2})-[:CHILD_OF*]->(i:Category)
WITH [x in nodes(path) | id(x)] AS nodeIds
MATCH (n1:Category)<-[:MISSING_IN]-(p)
WHERE id(n1) in nodeIds
RETURN p
```